# OR-ing strings to avoid nil in objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

Is there a short syntax for avoiding passing a nil NSString?

I want to avoid doing this:

```
if(!str)
   str = @"";
[obj someFunc:str];
```

Here's what I'd *like* to do:

```
[obj someFunc:(str || @"")]
```

But Objective-C won't allow it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The C-way to do in-line conditional expressions is:

```
[obj someFunc:(str ? str : @"")];
```

It's known colloquially as the “ternary operator” (the C standard calls it the “conditional operator”). It is used as:

```
condition ? true-expression : false-expression
```

If the condition is non-zero, the `true-expression` is evaluated as the result of the operator, otherwise the `false-expression` is evaluated as the result.

Comment: And if you dont like the ternary operator, you could always make a macro to do this:

#define NONNILSTR( foo ) ( foo ? foo : @"" )

or even...

#define STRINGOR( ifnonnil, ifnil ) ( ifnonnil ? ifnonnil : ifnil )